# Why can't I use `su --session-command` on Ubuntu?

Tags: su

In trying to solve a problem, I discovered the `--session-command` argument to `su`, as documented [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html). I tried to use it on my Ubuntu 12.04 system at work, but got an 'unrecognized option' error. Sure enough, it doesn't even show up on the man page for `su`!

The linked manpage does say `--session-command` is 'discouraged' but doesn't say why.

Out of curiosity, I connected to a CentOS 6.2. server at my work, and `--session-command` is recognized.

Further research led me to discover that the `su` used by Ubuntu comes from the `login` package, whereas in CentOS it comes from `coreutils`. Ubuntu also has a `coreutils` package installed by default, but it doesn't contain the FSF's standard `su` implementation. A detailed comparison shows that `coreutils` from both distros contain 105 executable files, but there are several differences (most of which seem to just be the installed location of the files).

My question: Is `--session-command` left out of Ubuntu's (or Debian's) superuser command by design, or has Ubuntu's divergent implementation simply not caught up with FSF? If by design, what is the reasoning for the omission? Related question: Why not use *all* the FSF's GNU Utils, anyway?

I'm sure this is documented somewhere but google was not forthcoming, given my search criteria.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1@shadow-utils.html Note the *Another version of this page is provided by the shadow-utils project* on the top of the page you provided in your link. Although I don't know the specific reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu and Debian uses the shadow-utils package since a worthwhile (log file goes to 01 Jan 1996). The util-linux `su` was moved from coreutils to util-linux package recently, the version in coreutils needed to be specifically build with it (most distros didn't). Apparently the only reason is that Debian always used shadow-util own implementation instead of coreutils su.

---

The header you will notice a message saying that there's another [man page provided by the shadow-utils](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1@shadow-utils.html) package which is the same as Debian/Ubuntu uses. If you see the bottom of the man page if both Ubuntu and CentOS you will notice this too.

In summary you are reading the wrong man.

Comment: Although this doesn't answer my question, it is informative. Thanks.

Comment: @EricLambart actually it answers your question and beyond, you ask "why su parameter isn't available in Ubuntu but in CentOS?" which I answer "CentOS uses another package for su which Ubuntu doesn't"

Comment: I just edited in an attempt to clarify the question, but in the original (and current) text you'll see that through my own research I *already* understood that the two OSes use different packages to provide their respective implementations of `su`. And Ubuntu's `su` comes not from a `shadow-utils` package (`dpkg -l shadow*` shows there's no such thing), but one named `login`. My real question was, and is: WHY? Why does Debian/Ubuntu use a non-GNU implementation, lacking a useful feature? I suspect it is due to security concerns, but I was hoping for something more concrete. :)

Comment: @EricLambart apparently, going from what this [USENET list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.utilities.util-linux-ng/5881) says, su from the util-linux was moved from the coreutils package to util-linux, while Debian always used shadow-util.